# wordpress filtering out caps in wp_title? (UpperCase is changed to Uppercase)

Tags: filters, wp-title

Have been working with WP for years, but never noticed this until today:

I have just launched a new site for a customer, and they write their name like this: "ClientName" (with one letter capitalized in the middle of the name). But when we save the site title in settings=>general, it is changed to "Clientname" (with only the first letter capitalized)

Seems like some kind of filter, but I cant find anything about how I change it? Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Hm, doesn't do that for me, so I don't think it's standard behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't happening to me (I just checked with your example), so it must be something that's occurring in the theme or a plugin.   You could try searching all of the codebase for the [wp_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/) filter, but you might get a lot of results to sort through.  An easier option might be switching the theme to the default, or disabling plugins and then re-enabling them one by one until you find the culprit.

Comment: Argh... I was afraid of that... :) Only using a few select plugins here, and the theme is completely built from scratch. Turns out it is "WPML String translation" that is causing the problem, but luckily that one is relatively easy to make do without (really only used it to generate the po/mo-files), AND it seems like it only stopped me from editing the title, when I turned it off I could change it again, and when I turned it back on the title stayed with the "UpperCase" spelling, but I could again not change it.